# What is the function of the Clip option of Quad View?

Tags: 3d-view

I'm a Blender beginner and My Blender version 2.80 beta. I was reading about Quad View [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/views.html#quad-view). I do not understand the function of Clip option which I found in the Properties region under the "Quad View" section. When I turn it on or off, it seems it does nothing. The manual and pop up menu triggered by clip option says "Clip objects based on what is visible in other side views." I do not understand what it means. Can anyone help me by explaining this a little bit thoroughly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the names says it clips whatever is outside view.

In the case of a quad view, if you pan or move one of the orthographic views (front, top, left or right) whatever goes outside that specific viewport gets clipped or hidden in the other ones (except for perspective views).

If in top view you pan your scene in such way that part of the objects stay out of that viewport, then those objects also get hidden in the other views as well, despite being visible otherwise.

[image]